# SQL sum of previous entries

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table:

```
year   val
----   ----
2013    4
2014    6
2014    2
2014    6
2015    1
2015    3
2016    7
```

is there a way to get the sum of the previous years for every year in the table?
the result should be like this:

```
2013   0
2014   4
2015   18
2016   22
2017   29
```

I tried something like this:

```
select year, sum(val) from 
(select year, val from table ?????)
group by year
```

There should be an inner join somewhere maybe?

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. In time, this may prove problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want old years only then use this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT year , ( SELECT SUM(val) FROM table as temp2 WHERE temp2.year < temp1.year ) as v FROM table as temp1
```

If you want to include year too then change temp2.year < temp1.year to <= , if you want to filter by years , then use comparison =

so

```
SELECT DISTINCT year , ( SELECT SUM(val) FROM table as temp2 WHERE temp2.year <= temp1.year ) as v FROM table as temp1
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT year , ( SELECT SUM(val) FROM table as temp2 WHERE temp2.year = temp1.year ) as v FROM table as temp1
```

but the latest could be easily done without subquery , just selecting year and sum(val) then group by year

Comment: I ended up using this answer because it was the only one that didn't use variables. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit challenging because you want `0` for the first year:

```
select year,
       ( (@p := @p + sumval) - sumval) as cumeprev
from (select year, sum(val) as sumval
      from table t
      group by year
     ) t cross join
     (select @p := 0) params
order by year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select year, @previous := @previous + sum(val)
from your_table
cross join (select @previous := 0) p
group by year
order by year
```